# Referring to a specific parameter-object outside of a method

Tags: object, parameters

Basically I need to access variables from an object which is passed as a parameter inside of a method. 
Ill give some pseudo code instead of the real code I'm using right now, for an easier-to-understand example for other users.

```
   public class AClass{
      Object x = null;

      private void doSomething(){
          method("something", new RandomClass());
          x = *the object of new RandomClass()*
      }
   }
```

I'll change the tags and title if there is a need for me to post the specific example, but I think this is a question for multiple languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a few minutes I figured out how to fix this specific problem.

```
public class AClass{
      Object x = null;

      private void doSomething(){
          Object y = new RandomClass();
          method("something", y);
          x = y;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some languages let us use them with pass-by-reference. Some don't. Therefore, first you should know whether the language you use has this kind of option or not. For example C++ can allow us to use it by pass-by-reference. In C++ , there are pointers and references. And we can use it like that:

```
int main()
{
    Object  r ;
    Object  k ;


    r.data=1;
    k.data=2;
    cout<<r.data<<" "<<k.data<<endl;
    method(r,k);
    cout<<r.data<<" "<<k.data<<endl;


    return 0;
}

void method(Object & x, Object & y){  // pass-by-reference
    x.data=4;
    y.data=5;

}
```

Output will be:

```
1 2
4 5
```

Also it is important that the variables of the object that you want to access are private or public.If it is not a friend function or not a function inside of that class, you cannot access that variables. 
Hope it helps.